# How to use THREE.GeometryUtils.center with .obj model

Tags: three.js, center

I use THREE.OBJLoader for import model obj I use code from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html#L75 and i insert  THREE.GeometryUtils.center for move model tothe original

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

```
                var object = event.content;

                for ( var i = 0, l = object.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                    object.children[ i ].material.map = texture;

                }

                object.position.y = - 80;
                scene.add( object );

            });
            THREE.GeometryUtils.center(object);
            loader.load( 'obj/001939.obj');
```

I show error in firefox is"a.computeBoundingBox() is not function".Idon't know why show it's error. Iuse firfox version 17.0.1